# What is the Universal Church of the Kingdom of God?

Tags: religious-practice, comparative-christianity, pentecostalism, latin-america

What is an overview of the practices, doctrines, and goals of the [Universal Church of the Kingdom of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Church_of_the_Kingdom_of_God) that distinguish it from other Evangelical and Pentecostal groups active in Latin America?

Comment: What, specifically, are you looking for that isn't in the Wikipedia article on that denomination? (I realize that the link was added by someone else.) Also, "other Christian groups active in Latin America" is quite broad. Are you looking for comparison with any particular branch of Christianity active in Latin America? Catholics? Protestants? Conservative Evangelical and Pentecostal sects?

Comment: @LeeWoofenden I'm looking for an insightful and detailed comparison of the group's practices, doctrines, and goals in Latin America and worldwide and that from a scholarly Christian perspective.

Comment: Scoping it to a comparison with other Evangelical and Pentecostal groups will, I think, make it much more manageable.

Comment: Even after scoping it to an Evangelical or Pentecostal comparison, this still seems very, very broad. An answer would essentially be more like an encyclopedia entry.

Comment: @PaulDraper As an _overview_ question, its answers are not expected to present a complete treatment of the question. They should touch on main differences about doctrines and practices considered essential or fundamental, or doctrines and practices that stand out especially in contrast. It's certainly manageable.

Answer (score 3):

It's a charismatic denomination that has been founded in Brazil, in 1977. Its current leader is the bishop Edir Macedo, founder of this denomination. They affirm to have an orthodox doctrine, Bible-based stance (but close to Pentecostals), but in practice they sell miracles and healings, and the "power" of the Holy Ghost to perform those manifestations (like Simon the Magician, who has been baptised and then rebuked by the Apostle Peter because Simon offered money to buy the gift of the Holy Spirit, according to Acts 8:18-24). In some parts of Latin America (or all), this church is known as "Pare de sufrir" ("Stop suffering"). The orthodox Christianity, especially the most-conservative group, agrees that this church is heretic, counted as a sect or cult.

[Important info about "Pare de sufrir", in Spanish](http://www.sectas.org/notas/paredesufrir.asp)

Comment: Welcome Tino! Thanks for posting this helpful answer.  If you'd like to strengthen it further, I'd recommend adding sources (even ones not in English) to show that this analysis doesn't merely reflect your opinion.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: I updated my reply. Please PM me if some additional info is required. Thanks in advance, God bless.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks also for offering an answer, and for providing a link to support it.